# java how to run spark app within apache server

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, spark-java

I have a Spark MVC app, which is very simple.

According to [spark documentation](http://sparkjava.com/documentation.html), this should be enough to run the app:

```
public class SparkServer {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Spark.staticFileLocation("src/main/webapp");
        System.out
                .println("bla bla bla");
        RService rService = new SparqlRService();
        new RController(rService);
    }
}
```

I put that class in a package inside my project, and I run the web app (dynamic web app) on Apache Tomcat server.

The print statement doesn't appear when run Apache Tomcat, that means this class is not being called. **I know it makes sense**. that is why i am asking. please how can I let Apache Tomcat run my spark app?

#### Update

After [@mlk answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35653444/2038257), i did the following:

```
public class SparkServer implements SparkApplication {

    @Override
    public void init() {
        Spark.staticFileLocation("src/main/webapp");
        System.out
                .println("bla bla lba");
        RService rService = new SparqlRService();
        new RController(rService);
    }
}
```

and in my web.xml i did:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
    <display-name>SRecommender</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>SparkFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>spark.servlet.SparkFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>
    applicationClass</param-name>
            <param-value>com.srecommender.SparkServer</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>SparkFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Where my SparkServer is in a package:
`com.recommender` that exists in a source folder: `src/main/java`

I run apache tomcat, but still when i call any path from spark, it is returning 404.

**HITE** i can run spark from the main method and call my pages, they are working. so the problem with the way i configured spark to run in apache tomcat

#### Update 2

This is how to set the path of the view

```
public RecommendationController(RecommendationService service) {
        get("/", (request, response) -> {

            Map<String, Object> model = new HashMap<>();
            model.put("data", "forza ROMA");
            model.put("data2", "It's Rome, It's home");

            return View("src/main/webapp/template/index.html", model);
        });
```

Comment: I think this question is mistagged: you should use [tag:apache-spark] instead of [tag:spark-java].

Answer (score 2):

Spark comes with a container built in, so you don't need tomcat or jetty. If you want to deploy to a full blow container then [you can by creating a web.xml file](http://sparkjava.com/documentation.html#other-webserver) and implementing [`spark.servlet.SparkApplication`](http://spark.screenisland.com/spark/servlet/SparkApplication.html).

Edit: you are missing the applicationClass property in your Web.xml.

Comment: thanks that is what i was looking for, i already have web.xml, the page your've mentioned listed a filter, however, you've said, spark application, could you tell me please who my web.xml have? I really appreciate it.

Comment: I've updated my answer to show you what I've tried after your appreciated answer, may you have al look please ?

Comment: You are missing applicationClass in your Web. Xml

Comment: if you mean i have to do `com.srecommender.SparkServer ` then i already tried that as well, but still not working.

Comment: Please post the complete web.xml for what you have tried. The one posted about does not include a applicationClass parameter on the filter.

Comment: Are you attempting to access static resources or none static? Do either work?

Comment: are you talking about the SparkServer class? it is not static, i showed you my web.xml could you check please if i did any mistake?

Answer (score 1):

WebApps don't execute `static void main()` methods, they bootstrap according to their `web.xml` from their deployed WAR file.

Do you have any experience with running webapps? You need a container like Tomcat or Jetty. Apache server is just for serving HTTP and is not an application container in itself.

Comment: Spark contains a jetty built-in, so you can start it with a `main` method.

Comment: The OP is asking about a "dynamic web app", so the assumption here is that more than just Spark is required.

Comment: @Marco yes Jersey code will be packaged into a WAR and deployed to an application container (more specifically a servlet container)

Comment: @Brad thanks, let's try the answer or MLK first, it should like a native container from spark. then if not working with me, i ll try jersey